# Xcode 11-Swift, CocoaPods ChameleonFramework compiler error

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I tried to include ChameleonFramework to my app so I added `pod 'ChameleonFramework/Swift'` to my pod file and installed 2.1.0 version + updated the pod.

After I build the app I get Swift Compiler Error. Looking at the errors, they are all call errors with missing parentheses since I didn't want to touch the code I didn't added the parentheses. Is there anyway I can fix this?

[Swift Compiler Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoETA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your Pod, it seems that it hasn't received any update recently:

Last release is from `Oct 5, 2016`.

I have looked in the issues and other people are asking the same fix :

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/viccalexander/Chameleon/issues/242)

You can try this fork : https://github.com/luckychris/Chameleon

Comment: you sir is a hero among men